# ListView item doesn't fit width in binding WinRT

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, winrt-xaml, listviewitem

I'm designing a listview in blend and I would like the item completely fill up the width of the list. This happens if I use the ListViewItem control, but if I use the data binding the item is tight. How can I fix this? thanks for the help and sorry for my bad english

Using ListViewItem:
[image: using ListViewItem with custom styles]

Using DataBinding
[image: using data binding]